# Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given for array_merge ()

Tags: php, null, array-merge

My wp-includes\widgets.php has this section which includes the line that throws this error.

> function _register_widget_update_callback( $id_base, $update_callback, $options = array(), ...$params ) {
> global $wp_registered_widget_updates;
>
> if ( isset( $wp_registered_widget_updates[ $id_base ] ) ) {
> if ( empty( $update_callback ) ) {
> unset( $wp_registered_widget_updates[ $id_base ] );
> }
> return;
> }
>
> $widget = array(
> 'callback' => $update_callback,
> 'params'   => $params,
> );
> //add check for null
> remove any NULL elements
> //$sidebars_widgets = array_filter($sidebars_widgets);
>
> end null check
> $widget                                   = array_merge( $widget, $options );
> //error on the above line : array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given in \wp-includes\widgets.php on line 613
> $wp_registered_widget_updates[ $id_base ] = $widget;
> }

commented line identifies the line above it as the line number pointed to in the error.  What do I need to change to get rid of the error?

Not even sure what to try here.

Comment: Please format your code in a code block (`{}` button), not as a quote. It's unreadable as is. Make sure it's a [mcve].